# Teechart smooth Line

Tags: activex, teechart

Want kind of chart type should I select to draw a chart similar to below and also how can I show statistic summary on chart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TeeChart ActiveX comes with a set of examples contained in a demo program we call "Features Demo". Find it at your TeeChart ActiveX installation folder, at **\Examples\Visual Basic\TeeChartAXv2014Demo\TeeChartFeatureDemo.exe**

- The example at **All Features\Welcome !\Tools\Series Stats** shows you how to easily get some statistics from a series and show them.
- The example at **All Features\Welcome !\Chart Styles\Statistical\Histogram\Histogram Transparency** show you a Histogram series, that would be the most appropriate to draw the green histogram in your image.
- There are some examples under **All Features\Welcome !\Functions** showing how to use different functions.

I'd open the example at **All Features\Welcome !\Basic Features** that shows an empty chart with access to the editor. I'd add a Histogram series through the editor (Series\Stats tab in the TeeChart Gallery) and then I'd try different Functions (Functions tab in the TeeChart Gallery) to find the most appropriate to your needs.

**EDIT:**

Here you have an example showing all the stats given by the tcSeriesStats tool in a tcRectangle tool:

```
  TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False

  TChart1.AddSeries scHistogram
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues 8

  Dim statsTool, rectTool As Integer
  statsTool = TChart1.Tools.Add(tcSeriesStats)

  rectTool = TChart1.Tools.Add(tcRectangle)
  With TChart1.Tools.Items(rectTool).asRectangle
    .AutoSize = True
    .Shape.Transparency = 0
  End With

  With TChart1.Tools.Items(statsTool).asSeriesStats
    .Series = TChart1.Series(0)

    TChart1.Tools.Items(rectTool).asRectangle.text = .Statistics.text
  End With
```

Comment: Hi yeray, How Can I display the stats values on the chart in a rectangle. Can I display the stats in the Rectangle tool if yes can you provide me an example.